# CAS proxy ticket

Tags: security, cas

In what cases the statement below might return null?

```
assertion.getPrincipal().getProxyTicketFor("myURL")
```

assertion is of org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Assertion type.

P.S. The reason behid this question is that we have read documentation and followed instructions. The line above works for some of us, and same thing doesn't work for me.
Security Certificates were suspected at first. I fixed them, but still it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a problem. I've not fixed certificates right. Certificate for Cas Client server was not valid.
I created two new "valid" certificates and imported them into trust stores of two servers (CAS and CAS client server), and specified path to trust stores for JBoss AS7 and Tomcat 6.
Now I am getting proxy tickets as expected.